# The Probability of getting more tails than heads

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

we toss a fair coin n times, what is the probability that the number of the total Heads is greater than the number of the Tail?
Let X the number of heads, then X has Binomial distribution with parameters n and p.
The problem here is to calculate the probability $P(X>\frac{n}{2})$.\
We have $P(X>\frac{n}{2})=\displaystyle\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^{n}P(x=k)=\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^{k=n}c^{k}_{n}(\frac{1}{2})^n$.

My question here, how we can simplify this expression?

Comment: if $p=1/2$ and $n$ is odd then the probability that you want is $1/2$

Comment: If $n$ is odd , the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$ which can be seen by considering the symmetry. If $n$ is even, you just need the probability $P$ for exactly $\frac{n}{2}$ times "heads" and the desired probability is then $\frac{1-P}{2}$

Comment: thank you for your time

Comment: @Peter but why the probability of getting exactly $\frac{n}{2}$ is equal a $\frac{1-P}{2}$

Comment: No, the probability to get more "heads" is $\frac{1-P}{2}$ , if $P$ is the probability for a tie between "heads" and "tails"

Comment: if $P$ is the probability of getteing $\frac{n}{2}$ heads, then why the desired probability is $\frac{1-P}{2}$? Thank you for your time

Comment: Every sequence with more "heads" corresponds $1-1$ with a sequence with more "tails" (you just have to swap "heads" and "tails") , so the probability for more "tails" and that for more "heads" are equal. One would this also expect intuitively considering a simple coin tossing game.

Comment: thank you very much, now i follow your logique. Thank you for your time sir.

Answer (score 0):

~Not an offical answer~

An intuitive way to think, is to approximate normal dis. (since the success is $\frac{1}{2}$).

For **a large enough** $n$, ($n \to \infty$): $P(H > T) = P(H - T > 0)$. Considering $H - T$, as its own distribution, $E(H - T) = 0$, we have $P(H - T > 0) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The probability of a tie is never $0$ (for even $n$) although it tends to $0$ for $n\to \infty$. But the intuition that the probability for more "heads" is close to $\frac{1}{2}$ , if $n$ is large , is correct.

Comment: @Peter Yes, I intended that with "large enough n". Apologies if unclear, I will edit.